# C# WinForms Base UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, user-controls

I'm having some problems in VS2019 with UserControls.

I have a base user control (WinForms) that I want all my other User Controls to be inherited from. THe base control provides a number of common properties that I need.

```
public partial class MyBaseControl : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{

    internal Int32 _caseID;
    internal object _objectID;

    public int CaseID { get => _caseID; set => _caseID = value; }
    public object ObjectID { get => _objectID; set => _objectID = value; }

    internal virtual void MakeScreenReadOnly()
    {
    }
    public MyBaseControl()
    {
        Type systemType = this.GetType();
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = systemType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        this.AutoScroll = true;

    }

}
```

The controls that inherit this base control all work fine when the application runs, except I can't view the control in the designer. The user control is

```
public partial class AddressControl : MyBaseControl
    {
....
}
```

I get the error

```
The service System.Windows.Forms.Design.IEventHandlerService already exists in the service container. Parameter name: serviceType
```

when trying to view AddressControl in the designer.

This used to work, in earlier version of Visual Studio. Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: Something interesting I have discovered. THe solution consists of 3 projects, a Data Access library (.Net Framework), UI (the WinForms project containing the controls as detailed) and a support Library (.NET Core). If I remove the Support Library and reference the compiled DLL, it seems to be all fine. If I reference the project, that is when I get projects. The UI projects references both the Data Access and the Support librarys, and the Support library references the Data Access library

Comment: shouldnt the user control constructor contain InitializeComponent();?

Comment: I have added it but it didn't fix the issue

Comment: did you do a clean rebuild after?

Comment: Remove that reflection thing. In a UserControl you can set `this.DoubleBuffered = true;` or `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);` in its constructor. -- See that you don't have duplicated attributes, e.g., `[Designer(GetType(...)]` in both base and derived classes. In this case, remove the attribute form the derived class. -- Don't do anything Design-time/Design-Mode related in the base class (check `if (DesignMode) (...)`), especially in the `Load` event. If something needs to be set, override `OnHandleCreated()` or `OnLayout()` or both.

Comment: I did do a clean build after and still getting the issue. I'm getting the issue after creating empty controls (with no code) and there was nothing in the Load event, so I'm fairly certain it is related the Support library that is in the project (if I remove the project reference it is all fine, even if I add reference the DLL directly).

Answer (score 0):

- Quit from Visual Studio.
- Open File Explorer: navigate to the folder that contains your project.
- Delete the “bin” and “obj” folders.
- Open Visual Studio again and open and recompile the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to recreate the user control.

Exclude the old control from the project to keep it on disk.

Move the old files outside the project folder (`MyBaseControl.cs` & `MyBaseControl.Designer.cs`).

Use the `Project > Add > User control` wizard.

Copy your old code in it.

And don't remove the `InitializeComponent();` from the constructor: add your code after.

It may work and solve your problem if Visual Studio is not corrupted else you can try repair or to uninstall and reinstall it.

Here what I tried:

- I added this usercontrol:

  ```
  public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
  {
    public UserControl1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
  ```
- I compile.
- I added another usercontrol and change the parent:

  ```
  public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl1
  {
    public UserControl2()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
  ```

It works fine and the designer display both correctly.

Next I added your code **while keeping the `InitializeComponent()` call**:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
  internal Int32 _caseID;
  internal object _objectID;

  public int CaseID { get => _caseID; set => _caseID = value; }
  public object ObjectID { get => _objectID; set => _objectID = value; }

  internal virtual void MakeScreenReadOnly()
  {
  }
  public UserControl1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    Type systemType = this.GetType();
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = systemType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    this.AutoScroll = true;
  }
}
```

I compile.

All works fine too.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work either. I'm going to try on my home PC this evening to see if I'm getting the same behaviour there, but I attempt a uninstall/install

Comment: What happens if you create a new user control without changing anything: are you able to open the designer and see the empty control surface?

Comment: Yes, and if I change AddressControl to inherit from UserControl, it displays correctly as well.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I can't see UserControl2 in this case. I'm getting a different error relating to my Support DLL (see my comment on the original post). I'm beginning to think that the Support DLL is causing issues for some reason. Not sure why is the only problem.